# List of IE6 Upgrade / Denial Pages

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

As we transition away from IE6, I'm trying to find examples of other sites that stopped supporting IE6 and encourage their users to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BringDownIE6](http://www.bringdownie6.com/) has a simple example consisting of some HTML inside IE tags (`<!--[if lt IE 7]>`) to display a message to IE6 users.

Whilst not examples of active sites that have stopped supporting IE6, [IE6Update](http://ie6update.com/#) and [StopIE6](http://www.stopie6.com/widgets.html#wrap) both show different methods of alerting users to upgrade.

Comment: This should suffice for our purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[YouTube](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/07/14/youtube-will-be-next-to-kiss-ie6-support-goodbye) will show a message to the user suggesting they upgrade to a modern browser.

Also, today Google announced they will no longer support it on their [Google Docs and Google Sites](http://www.techcrunch.com/2010/01/29/google-twists-knife-in-ie6-pulls-support-from-docs-and-sites/). They've already updated their [requirements](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37560) and IE6 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals [Facebook](http://syntacticsugar.nl/2009/04/25/facebook-ditches-support-for-ie6/) is trying to do that.